# rkhunter suspicious file type ecryptfs-user-Private text

Tags: rkhunter

Should I be concerned about this warning?

```
Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
[18:17:04]  /dev/shm/ecryptfs-user-Private: ASCII text
```

I deleted the file, but when I rebooted it was recreated.
Is this normal, or has my system been compromised? If so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the file's content? Be aware that `rkhunter` telling you "`Suspicious...`" means that you should investigate further.

Beginning with `rm -f` curtails the investigation, and can break your system.

`rkhunter` complains that it found an "`ASCII Text`" file in the `/dev` directory tree, which usually holds device files. This can, in some cases,  point to a problem. In the history of Computer Security, `root` kits have hidden files in `/dev` to conceal them, thus `rkhunter` looks for "funny looking" files.

This particular file looks like a part of an `ecryptfs` encrypted file system installation.

Investigate further with `dpkg -S`  to see if it's part of a package.

"Delete on Warning" is not a good plan.

Has `rkhunter` been updated recently? Does it know about `ecryptfs`? `apt-get changelog rkhunter`?

Comment: The contents of the file is just the number 2. I'm not sure what I am or am not looking for, when I use dpkg -S ecryptfs. How would that search verify if the file is okay, or not?